# Getting different results when adding if or else to selenium google webdriver using python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I see different results when retrieving the network data using `window.performance.getEntries()`

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/','https://www.google.com/']

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    image_name = url.split(".")[1] + ".png"
    driver.save_screenshot(image_name)
    performance_data = driver.execute_script('return window.performance.getEntries();')
    for single_data in performance_data:
        file = open('Hero.txt', 'a')
        files = open('Heroes.txt', 'a')
        files.write(str(single_data["name"]))
        if "stack" in single_data["name"]:
            file.write(url + "stack_code 1")
            break

        if "stack" not in single_data["name"]:
            file.write(url + "stack_code 0")
            break
```

If I remove the last `if` statement I get all the network call names in Heroes.txt. So the code works with the first `if` as it is populated correctly. If I add the second `if`:

```
if "stack" not in single_data["name"]:
    file.write(url + "stack_code 0")
    break
```

I get this in Heroes.txt:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/https://www.google.com/https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.pnghttps://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.pnghttps://consent.google.com/status?continue=https://www.google.com&pc=s&timestamp=1534340797&gl=GBhttps://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i2_2ec824b0.pngfirst-paintfirst-contentful-painthttps://www.google.com/gen_204?s=webhp&t=aft&atyp=csi&ei=vS50W_aGHKSalwSCgrLQCQ&rt=wsrt.107,aft.119,prt.119https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.pnghttps://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en_GB.LsN8oH7x4FY.O/m=sx,sb,cdos,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/am=YBZhP_4BJP-_YEBRsBWMsMAMCoZN/rt=j/d=1/dg=0/rs=ACT90oHhp5AGyfczYrjBNR_VenselWZSnAhttps://www.google.com/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.icohttps://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en_GB.LsN8oH7x4FY.O/am=YBZhP_4BJP-_YEBRsBWMsMAMCoZN/rt=j/d=1/exm=sx,sb,cdos,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/ed=1/dg=0/rs=ACT90oHhp5AGyfczYrjBNR_VenselWZSnA/m=aa,abd,async,bgd,dvl,foot,ipv6,lu,m,mu,sf,sonic,spch,cbin,tnqaT,cbhb,xz7cCd,fEVMic,WgDvvc?xjs=s1https://www.google.com/gen_204?atyp=csi&ei=vS50W_aGHKSalwSCgrLQCQ&s=webhp&t=all&imc=3&imn=3&imp=0&adh=&conn=onchange&ima=1&ime=0&imeb=0&imeo=0&mem=ujhs.10,tjhs.14,jhsl.2330,dm.8&net=dl.10000,ect.4g,rtt.0&sys=hc.4&rt=aft.118,dcl.121,iml.118,ol.137,prt.118,xjs.297,xjsee.297,xjses.222,xjsls.138,wsrt.107,cst.15,dnst.0,rqst.81,rspt.9,sslt.13,rqstt.17,unt.1,cstt.2,dit.228&zx=1534340797851https://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.pnghttps://www.google.com/async/bgasy?ei=vS50W_aGHKSalwSCgrLQCQ&yv=3&async=_fmt:jspbhttps://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en_GB.LsN8oH7x4FY.O/am=YBZhP_4BJP-_YEBRsBWMsMAMCoZN/rt=j/d=1/exm=sx,sb,cdos,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi,aa,abd,async,bgd,dvl,foot,ipv6,lu,m,mu,sf,sonic,spch,cbin,tnqaT,cbhb,xz7cCd,fEVMic,WgDvvc/ed=1/dg=0/rs=ACT90oHhp5AGyfczYrjBNR_VenselWZSnA/m=RMhBfe?xjs=s2https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/k=og.og2.en_US.gQBLNoMk7Q0.O/rt=j/m=def/exm=in,fot/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTuPdnXARx6L0IfRJ8krP-HTrx9fswhttps://www.google.com/gen_204?atyp=i&ei=vS50W_aGHKSalwSCgrLQCQ&vet=10ahUKEwi22cnxmO_cAhUkzYUKHQKBDJoQsmQIDQ..s&zx=1534340797919https://adservice.google.com/adsid/google/uihttps://www.google.com/gen_204?atyp=i&ct=&cad=udla=3&ei=vS50W_aGHKSalwSCgrLQCQ&e=12&zx=1534340797933https://www.google.co.uk/domainless/read?igu=1https://www.google.com/js/bg/5KdFGiZjrMqKMsWhJOuJJel3qQCRBLUAy7GSORuI-sg.jshttps://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.yK0z3MKtgaU.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AHpOoo-SafOYj4n3budMysbWxppU-lxJeg/cb=gapi.loaded_0https://www.google.com/domainless/write?igu=1&data=&xsrf=ALAmJdGvY5TXvkklyYKZuaWBzGhopICz3A:1534340797490https://www.google.com/gen_204?atyp=i&ct=&cad=udla=3&ei=vS50W_aGHKSalwSCgrLQCQ&pd=105&e=2&zx=1534340798039https://www.google.com/gen_204?atyp=i&ct=&cad=udla=1&ei=vS50W_aGHKSalwSCgrLQCQ&act=p&ps=2&zx=1534340798039
```

As soon as I add the second `if` I get this in Heroes.txt:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/https://www.google.com/
```

Any ideas? Am I doing something silly :/

Comment: What's the expected result here?

Comment: @musikreck The result I get before adding the second if statement . Which is all the network  call names. When adding the second if statement I get only the domain names. So if there is stack in the network call name then show stack_code_1 if not then stack_code_0.

Comment: For simplicity, just use an if-else statement, rather than 2 if's. Another thing, don't keep opening the files on every iteration of `performance_data`. Check if `performance_data` contains anything, then if so open the files once and work on them.

Comment: @musikreck I changed it to two if's as it was doing the same behaviour with if-else.

Comment: So I guess your issue is that your conditional statements, which don't involve Heroes.txt, are seemingly affecting what gets written to Heroes.txt?

Comment: @musikreck yes, different results in Heroes.txt based on the conditional statements.

Comment: Your if statements write to hero.txt not heros.txt, so there is something wrong with your claim.

Comment: @Ywapom heroes.txt shows the network calls so I can manually see if the logic worked. The output of the logic writes to hero.txt.

Answer (score 0):

## What is happening:

The reason your code writes differently when you insert the second `if` condition is that there are times when the second condition is met, thus `break`ing from your `for` loop iterating over `performance_data`. If you removed the second `if` condition, then when `'stack' not in single_data["name"]`, there'd be no `break` and you'd continue onto the next iteration of the `for` loop and continue writing to `Heroes.txt`.

## Making sense of things:

When you add the second `if` statement, you only have 2 values written to `Heroes.txt`, since you're guaranteed a `break` from the `for` loop, but you're iterating over 2 URLs.

When you remove the second `if` statement, you're not always guaranteed a `break` from the `for` loop, thus (usually) providing you with more values written to `Heroes.txt`.

## Suggestion:

This is a logic issue, not a Selenium or Python issue. If you can tell us what your expected output is, or what you want written to the files, we can help structure your code to accomplish that expectation.

---

Based on my guess, you probably want something like this (I've removed some code that was unused in this post):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/','https://www.google.com/']

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    performance_data = driver.execute_script('return window.performance.getEntries();')

    pass_flag = False

    for single_data in performance_data:
        # As opposed to breaking or continuing, we're just going to pass over
        # to the next bit of code where we write to Heroes.txt after we've
        # written to Hero.txt once per URL
        if pass_flag:
            pass 
        else:
            if 'stack' in single_data['name']:
                file = open('Hero.txt', 'a')
                file.write(url + 'stack_code 1')
            if 'stack' not in single_data['name']:
                file = open('Hero.txt', 'a')
                file.write(url + 'stack_code 0')
            pass_flag = True 

        # Unlike the above, we're *always* going to write to Heroes.txt
        files = open('Heroes.txt', 'a')
        files.write(str(single_data['name']))
```

The result from `Hero.txt`:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/stack_code 1https://www.google.com/stack_code 0
```

The result from `Heroes.txt`:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.jshttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=c8d9d8cf9f8ahttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=bfa43f7a5209https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary-unified.css?v=ebcfa5178eebhttps://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/5d55j.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/xKsQb.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/NT6zO.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/9J8MK.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/r0io0.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/EQnZM.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/8UH0j.pnghttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45https://i.stack.imgur.com/817gJ.pnghttps://cdn.sstatic.net/img/hero/pattern.svg?v=13ca42e6c21dfirst-paintfirst-contentful-painthttps://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=04d772c81312https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.jshttps://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=08c43b9ad64chttps://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.jshttps://secure.quantserve.com/quant.jshttps://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.jshttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js?v=5f2ad1ab6af9https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=stackoverflow.comhttps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_239.jshttps://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/styles/clc.min.css?v=f28c677e209bhttps://stackoverflow.com/gps/eventhttps://rules.quantcount.com/rules-p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.jshttps://www.google-analytics.com/r/collecthttps://sb.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=2&c2=17440561&ns__t=1534347714086&ns_c=UTF-8&cv=3.1&c8=Stack%20Overflow%20-%20Where%20Developers%20Learn%2C%20Share%2C%20%26%20Build%20Careers&c7=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&c9=https://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel;r=767658432;rf=0;a=p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc;url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F;fpan=1;fpa=P0-551429989-1534347714162;ns=0;ce=1;qjs=1;qv=4c19192-20180628134937;cm=;ref=;je=0;sr=2048x1152x24;enc=n;dst=1;et=1534347714161;tzo=420;ogl=type.website%2Curl.https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow%252Ecom%2F%2Csite_name.Stack%20Overflow%2Cimage.https%3A%2F%2Fcdn%252Esstatic%252Enet%2FSites%2Fstackoverflow%2Fimg%2Fapple-touch-icon%402%252Epng%3Fv%3D73d79a8%2Ctitle.Stack%20Overflow%20-%20Where%20Developers%20Learn%252C%20Share%252C%20%26%20Build%20Careers%2Cdescription.Stack%20Overflow%20%7C%20The%20World%E2%80%99s%20Largest%20Online%20Community%20for%20Developershttps://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_rendering_239.jshttps://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43dhttps://www.google.com/https://www.google.com/images/hpp/shield_privacy_checkup_green_2x_web_96dp.pnghttps://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.pnghttps://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.pnghttps://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4.woff2https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i2_2ec824b0.pngfirst-paintfirst-contentful-painthttps://www.google.com/gen_204?s=webhp&t=aft&atyp=csi&ei=yEl0W7-oHojz0wLly6CICA&rt=wsrt.359,aft.315,prt.315https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en_US.R6OYO7uDOhg.O/m=sx,sb,cdos,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/am=YBZhP_4BJP-_YEChYCsYYYEZFAyb/rt=j/d=1/dg=0/rs=ACT90oH8mcRSbgCKJPsRvB4s5dlgzuOWqg
```

I'm following the same structure that you used in your program in the solution above. Below is the way I would have done it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/','https://www.google.com/']

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    performance_data = driver.execute_script('return window.performance.getEntries();')

    pass_flag = False

    for single_data in performance_data:
        if pass_flag:
            pass 
        else:
            # Using with...as guarantees that the file is closed; also, we 
            # didn't have to rewrite 1 line of code
            with open('Hero.txt', 'a') as file:  
                if 'stack' in single_data['name']:
                    file.write(url + 'stack_code 1')
                else:
                    file.write(url + 'stack_code 0')
            pass_flag = True 

        # As above, using with...as guarantees that the file is closed
        with open('Heroes.txt', 'a') as files:
            files.write(str(single_data['name']))
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same behaviour using your code. If you change the urls order or even just use www.google.com in the array. Then you change the if to search for say adservice it doesn't pick this up. I tested this by writing to Heroes.txt and it doesn't give the full network names.

Comment: @Sam What output are you getting when you run my code? What are you expecting?

Comment: the output I am expecting is lets say I have 100 urls and in one of them there is www.google.com. When looking through the network names I want to write code 1 if adserv is there and 0 if it isn't for the given 100 urls. Stack will always work as it is in the domain name. But changing it to this it doesn't. Thanks